# Conditional row read of csv in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have large CSVs where I'm only interested in a subset of the rows.  In particular, I'd like to read in all the rows which occur before a particular condition is met.

For example, if `read_csv` would yield the dataframe:

```
     A    B      C
1   34   3.20   'b'
2   24   9.21   'b'
3   34   3.32   'c'
4   24   24.3   'c'
5   35   1.12   'a'
... 
1e9 42   2.15   'd'
```

is there some way to read all the rows in the csv until col B exceeds 10.  In the above example, I'd like to read in:

```
     A    B      C
1   34   3.20   'b'
2   24   9.21   'b'
3   34   3.32   'c'
4   24   24.3   'c'
```

I know how to throw these rows out once I've read the dataframe in, but at this point I've already spent all that computation reading them in.  I do not have access to the index of the final row before reading the csv (no [skipfooter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) please)

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this in the Pandas API. You'll probably just have to break out `csv`, grab the rows one at a time, stuff them in a list of lists, stop once you get the last row that you want, and then build a `DataFrame` out of the resulting list of lists.

Comment: You could read the csv in chunks and only append if the subset meets your condition

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could read the csv in chunks. Since `pd.read_csv` will return an iterator when the `chunksize` parameter is specified, you can use `itertools.takewhile` to read only as many chunks as you need, without reading the whole file.

```
import itertools as IT
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 10 ** 5
chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize, header=None)
chunks = IT.takewhile(lambda chunk: chunk['B'].iloc[-1] < 10, chunks)
df = pd.concat(chunks)
mask = df['B'] < 10
df = df.loc[mask]
```

---

Or, to avoid having to use `df.loc[mask]` to remove unwanted rows from the last chunk, perhaps a cleaner solution would be to define a custom generator:

```
import itertools as IT
import pandas as pd

def valid(chunks):
    for chunk in chunks:
        mask = chunk['B'] < 10
        if mask.all():
            yield chunk
        else:
            yield chunk.loc[mask]
            break

chunksize = 10 ** 5
chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize, header=None)
df = pd.concat(valid(chunks))
```

Comment: @DSM: Do you mean `chunk.ix[-1, 'B']`?

Comment: @DSM: Thanks, you're right. Even `chunk.ix[-1, 'B']` would return the wrong value  if `chunk`'s index included -1 as a value.

Answer (score 7):

> **Warning**: `pd.read_csv("filename.csv")` loads the entire `csv` into an in-memory `DataFrame` before processing it (thanks @BlackJack for pointing this out).  If the `csv` is big @unutbu answer is more appropriate (or perhaps another library like [`polars`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) which can read a file in chunks & apply multiple operations thanks to its query planner)

Building on @joanwa answer:

```py
df = (pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
      [lambda x: x['B'] > 10])
```

---

From Wes McKinney's "Python for Data Analysis" chapter
on "Advanced pandas":

We cannot refer to the result of load_data until it has been assigned to the temporary variable df. To help with this, assign and many other pandas functions accept function-like arguments, also known as callables.

To show callables in action, consider ...

```py
df = load_data()
df2 = df[df['col2'] < 0]
```

Can be rewritten as:

```py
df = (load_data()
      [lambda x: x['col2'] < 0])
```

Comment: Wow, this is magic!

Comment: Hi I was also working on similar csv but I want to read my csv file until a row with certain text say ‘unwanted’ is found. Can we do it with lambda function .

Comment: It's formatted quite confusing and not magic, and it's not a solution to the question, which asks for reading to stop, not to read all data into memory and then filter.  Also it gives different results because values in column "B" decrease below 10 again.

Comment: Thanks @Rachel & @BlackJack.  @Rachel this solution is not appropriate for that use case since as @BlackJack points out it loads the entire `csv` into memory

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `csv` module to calculate the appropriate row number. Then use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with the `nrows` argument:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import csv, copy

mycsv = StringIO(""" A      B     C
34   3.20   'b'
24   9.21   'b'
34   3.32   'c'
24   24.3   'c'
35   1.12   'a'""")

mycsv2 = copy.copy(mycsv)  # copying StringIO object [for demonstration purposes]

with mycsv as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)
    counter = next(idx for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if float(row[1]) > 10)

df = pd.read_csv(mycsv2, delim_whitespace=True, nrows=counter+1)

print(df)

    A      B    C
0  34   3.20  'b'
1  24   9.21  'b'
2  34   3.32  'c'
3  24  24.30  'c'
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of boolean indexing or giving callable, one can use `query`  method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.read_csv("my_data.csv").query("B < 10"))
```

I don't know how fast this solution is, however it should be faster then giving plain callable, especially lambda.

Comment: This does read the whole data into memory and *then* filters. So it doesn't answer the question.  Also it doesn't stop the first time the value exceeded 10.

Answer (score -2):

I would go the easy route described here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

```
df[df['B'] > 10]
```

Comment: this is now what op is asking for. this can be applied after reading the entire csv

Comment: He would like to save time and memory skiping useless rows

Comment: Also this (non-)solution doesn't yield the desired result, which is the rows up to the first time "B" values exceed 10.