# Group a huge csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, mapreduce, dask

I have a huge .csv file (above 100 GB) in the form:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5             | 
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------------------| 
| A       | B       | 35      | X       | 2017-12-19 11:28:34 | 
| A       | C       | 22      | Z       | 2017-12-19 11:27:24 | 
| A       | B       | 678     | Y       | 2017-12-19 11:38:36 | 
| C       | A       | 93      | X       | 2017-12-19 11:44:42 |
```

And want to summarize it

- by the unique values in Column1 and Column2
- with sum(Column3),
- max(Column5)
- the value of Column4, where Column5 was at its maximum.

Therefore the above extract should become:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | sum(Column3) | Column4 | max(Column5)        | 
|---------|---------|--------------|---------|---------------------| 
| A       | B       | 702          | Y       | 2017-12-19 11:38:36 | 
| A       | C       | 22           | Z       | 2017-12-19 11:27:24 | 
| C       | A       | 93           | X       | 2017-12-19 11:44:42 |
```

With these additional considerations:

- The .csv is not sorted
- I have python under windows
- The solution should be on a standalone PC (Cloud instances are not acceptable)
- I have tried Dask and the .compute() step (should it ever complete) will take about a week. Anything faster than this would be a good solution.
- I am open to all kinds of solutions - splitting the file into chunks, multiprocessing... whatever would work

**Edit 1:**
I had not used multiprocessing in dask. Adding it improves the speed signifficantly (as suggested by one of the comments), but the 32G RAM is not enough for this approach to complete.
**Edit 2:**
Dask 0.16.0 is not a possible solution, as it is absolutely broken. After 5 hours of writing partitions to disk, it has written 8 out of 300 partitions and after reporting to have written 7, now it reports having written 4, instead of 8 (without throwing an error).

Comment: have a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) or `csv` module .

Comment: @P.hunter Can they handle 100 GB when RAM is 16 GB?

Comment: Show what are you doing with dask.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel, df2=df.groupby(['Column1','Column2']).aggregate({'Column3':sum,'Column5':max}).compute()

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel, it does not matter what I did. I am looking for a better solution to the problem.

Comment: @BorislavAymaliev yes it does matter, because dask can be the solution if you use it properly.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel, I am open to solutions in dask. You can show me how to use it properly. What I have as a start is a .csv file, as explained in the question.

Comment: Do you mind to share you pc specs, the output of `df.npartitions` and `df.known_divisions` I ran your same code in dask using `from dask.multiprocessing import get` and writing `.compute(get=get)` for a similar dataframe (just a 30gb one instead of 100gb) and the elapsed time was 5 minutes.

Comment: @user32185 I am currently on an 8-threaded i7 with 32 GB of RAM, but I would like to be able to re-run the very same process flow on a mid-range hardware (i5, 16GB). I find your comment very useful, since I had not set the multiprocessing part. df.npartitions outputs 1584 and known_divisions is False. I already added `.compute(get=get)`, which sped up things. Should you have any other recommendations, I will be happy to read/use them.

Comment: @BorislavAymaliev could you tell me how much it took with `.compute(get=get)`?  I ran mine on a similar machine (i7 with 16gb of RAM).
You can try to play with divisions. Unfortunately at the moment I don't have other suggestions. Me too I'm struggling with dask...

Comment: @user32185 It should've completed in 10 hours, but could not. A `MemoryError` was raised after 2hr 45min 27.3s. at 15%.

Comment: @BorislavAymaliev I generated the dataframe(s) whit [this](https://pastebin.com/GPVTHmLL) and then just run `df2 = df.groupby(['Column1','Column2']).aggregate({'Column3':sum,'Column5':max}).compute(get=get)`
Have you tried to check the graph before compute?
I don't know if in your case a proper approach is to eventually split the dataframe in chunks (maybe saved as parquet) and then use dask. Another option can be to use this sort of [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28239777/4819376)

Comment: @user32185 So far nothing worked. I tried splitting the file into smaller chunks but if I change the default blocksize and write them to `to_csv('file*.csv')`, some files get written incomplete. If I dont change the default blocksize, then I have 1584 smaller files and was not able to condense (compute()) them in parallel. Condensing them 1 by 1 is painfully slow.