# Parallelizing pandas .groupby() and .agg() on chunks of a huge csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parallel-processing

I am trying to figure out how to parallelize (if possible) the pandas .groupby().agg() process. Here is an example set-up:

I have a huge (100+ GB) infile.csv file in the format:

```
| A | B | C | D | E |
|---|---|---|---|---|
| X | M | 1 | 4 | a |
| X | M | 2 | 3 | b |
| Y | M | 3 | 2 | c |
| Y | N | 4 | 1 | d |
```

Then I read it with pandas in big chunks with:

```
for rows in pd.read_csv(infile.csv, header = 0, index_col=False, chunksize = 6000000)
```

And do grouped aggregations with:

```
df=rows.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False).agg(['C':'sum','D':'max','E':count])
```

The output (which I append to another csv file) is:

```
| A | B | C | D | E   |
|   |   |sum|max|count|
|---|---|---|---|-----|
| X | M | 3 | 4 |  2  |
| Y | M | 3 | 2 |  1  |
| Y | N | 4 | 1 |  1  |
```

The problem is that this process consumes 20% of my RAM and 1 core of the processor. I believe it can be parallelized (and therefore sped up) at least 3 times on a desktop and more on a server. Any suggestions on how to do that?

My apologies if this has been answered already, but I did not manage to find a solution.

Comment: Sure, you could do this with `multiprocessing` to utilize all your cores. Might have to be careful with memory consumption...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you are absolutely correct. I intend to balance the memory consumption by changing the `chunksize`. The problem is that I could find only examples on how to use `multiprocessing` for row operations such as C+D.

Comment: I would consider using Dask DataFrame or even Apache Spark (HDFS, Hadoop Cluster) if you will need to process much bigger data sets - terabytes of data...

Comment: @MaxU, I have already tested dask dataframe with this problem. My conclusion was that it is either broken, or poorly documented. One time, after 5 hours, I got wrong indicators and no error from dask. If you are experienced with dask and can help, here is a link to my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884199/group-a-huge-csv-file-in-python