# Stop reading csv file in python when condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
Name    Age Sex
Mark    22  M
Helen   23  F
James   54  M
Mike    32  M
Jen     23  F
Julie   20  F
```

I am reading this csv file like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Students.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
```

How can I read in the dataset BUT the code has to stop when the "Name" is "Mike". So, the resulting dataframe would like:

```
Name    Age Sex
Mark    22  M
Helen   23  F
James   54  M
Mike    32  M
```

Comment: You can use something similar to done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239529/conditional-row-read-of-csv-in-pandas),

Comment: @lorenzofeliz that's the linked duplicate :P

Comment: thanks for marking the same