# read a text file with pandas with a condition on a column

Tags: python, csv

I have a huge text file which has 180 million rows like below:

[image]

I want to read this text file with pandas but only read lines which the "pdate" lies in a specific range. For example I want to read line which the "pdate" is between 981225 and 981229.
Since the whole text file is huge I don't want to read the whole file and then set the condition.
I want to just read those lines which my condition is true on them. Besides I need the fastest way and not read the file line by line.
Is there any solution?

Comment: What's about reading it line by line ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditional row read of csv in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239529/conditional-row-read-of-csv-in-pandas)

Comment: @AlexandreB. the line which holds my condition is around 100 million rows and I think read them line by line takes time.

Comment: @qaiser Actually I guess no cause in "unutbu" answer, the "chunks" variable reads the whole file  in chunks and then apply the "valid" function on it and in "jpp" answer, the file has been read line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this question is to convert the text file to CSV file. To know how to convert, read the following paragraph:

After getting the csv, Use this to access User range of data

```
df['two'].between(981225, 981229, inclusive=False)
```

How to Convert Text file into Csv File:

1. import the text file so that it can be read and interpreted as data. In Excel, this process is as simple as clicking the Data tab and then the From Text option.
2. At this point, you should be prompted to select the specific text file you would like to use from your computer. After locating the appropriate file, confirm the selection.
3. Once your file has been selected, a series of menu prompts will appear onscreen that allow you to specify how the data in your text file should be presented. This includes options for adjusting and creating break lines, as well as width ratios. Once you have customized your document as you see fit, you can press the "OK" button to finalize your selection.
4. At this point, your text file should be properly formatted into the various rows and cells needed to ensure full compatibility with the CSV format. Now, you can select the "Save As" function in your software and choose the CSV file format. Once this is complete, your text file will have been fully converted into the CSV format as planned.

Comment: which function do you use to read the data? I guess I don't get this line --df['two'].between(981225, 981229, inclusive=False) -- Do you read the df from pd.read_csv?

Comment: Please remove lots of paragraphs, and put clean compacts steps first. Then, you can explain your steps in detail. This distinction helps all kind of users (who need just the steps and not the explanation, and those who want to understand why these steps were taken).

Answer (score 0):

You can read it with the Pandas if you use it further. I don't if it is the best performance.

```
pd.read_csv(<file>, usecols=['..'], skiprows=<int>, nrows=<int>)
```

**usecols:** to select the column
**skiprows and nrows:** the frame that you want.

But if the Pandas is a lost of time for you you can do with the readline() from the *open* object.

```
extract = []
with open(<file>) as f:
    row_start = 500
    row_end = 520
    n = 0

    while n < row_start:
        f.readline()
        n += 1

    while n <= row_end:
        extract.append(f.readline())
        n += 1
```