# Speed up this conditional row read of csv file in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv

I modified a line from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239529/conditional-row-read-of-csv-in-pandas) to conditionally read rows from a csv file:

```
filename=r'C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\Projects\UK_Traffic_Data\test.csv'

df = (pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False) [lambda x: x['Accident_Index'].str.startswith('2005')])
```

This line works perfectly fine for a small test dataset. However, I do have a big csv file to read and it takes a very long time to read the file. Actually, eventually the `NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit` is reached. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to improve this code and its performance?
2. The records in the "Accident_Index" column are sorted. Therefore, it may be a solution to break out of the read statement if a value is reached where "Accident_Index" does not equal `str.startswith('2005')`. Do you have a suggestion on how to do that?

Here is some example data:

[image]

The desired output should be a pandas dataframe containing the top six records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could initially read just the specific column we want to filter on with the above conditions (assuming this reduces the reading overhead significantly) .

```
#reading the mask column
df_indx = (pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False,usecols=['Accident_Index'])
           [lambda x: x['Accident_Index'].str.startswith('2005')])
```

We could then use the values from this column to read the remaining columns from the file using the [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [nrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) properties since they are sorted values in the input file

```
df_data= (pd.read_csv(filename,    
         error_bad_lines=False,header=0,skiprows=df_indx.index[0],nrows=df_indx.shape[0]))
df_data.columns=['Accident_index','data']
```

This would give a subset of the data we want. We may not need to get the column names separately.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Praveen KR, this worked very nice and smooth !