# Pandas - Create dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to create a dataframe from a csv file, there are multiple columns and rows. One of the columns has either 'yes' or 'no'. I only want the dataframe to include rows that have 'yes'.
Can someone show me how to write this code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditional row read of csv in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239529/conditional-row-read-of-csv-in-pandas)

Comment: You can also try something like this df.loc[df['column_name'] == 'yes']

Comment: Python and Pandas have multiple options that you can use to filter under specific conditions. 
Quickly, here is a page I just found you https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-select-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-values-d3f5da421e93, but you can find many pages on google that can teach you other cool ways. don't limit yourself to learn all the cool stuff Pandas has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ways that can help you.
Say that your column name is `choice` and your data frame name is `df`

```py
df_new = df[df['choice'] == 'yes']
```

In this case, if you run df_new, you will get your datagram that only has `yes`.

Same to the code below.

```py
mask = df['choice'] == 'yes'
  
# new dataframe with selected rows
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df[mask])
```

You can also try this:

```py
# condition with df.values property
mask = df['choice'].values == 'yes'
  
# new dataframe
df_new = df[mask]
  
print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file then filter the dataframe to only get "yes" rows.For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df[df.column == 'yes']
```