# When using pandas to read an excel file, how do I only read in rows that contain certain words in a column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

The first column in my excel file either has nothing, 'INSERT', 'UPDATE' or 'DELETE' in the first column.  I need to load into a data frame only the rows that contain either 'INSERT', 'UPDATE' or 'DELETE'.  Right now I am using:

```
pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='PRIMITIVE',header=None,skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

to just skip the first 7 rows.  Possibly there is a way to only include the rows specified above.

Comment: Load the whole thing then drop the rows you don't need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditional row read of csv in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239529/conditional-row-read-of-csv-in-pandas)